# cell.contentView.viewWithTag vs cell.viewWithTag in didSelectItemAtIndexPath works different

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

My `UICollectionView` has a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView`, i figure it them and works well like this:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("coffee_brand_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) //as! AURCoffeeBrandCollectionViewCell
        let imageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView

        imageView?.image = UIImage(named: ["coffee1","coffee2","coffee3","coffee3"][indexPath.row])
        let name = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
        name?.text = coffeeName[indexPath.row] + String(indexPath.row)
        name?.textColor = UIColor(red: 226.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 119.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        name?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.backgroundColor = collectionView.backgroundColor
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.frame.width - 40)/2.0
        imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

        return cell
    }
```

But i can't get the selected cell's name and image like below,

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            if let name = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) {
                //Can't get into this.
            }
    }
}
```

and cell's contentView subviews return 0.

```
cell!.contentView.subviews
0 elements
```

**Update**:

`cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2)` works in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, but not in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. however `cell.viewWithTag(2)` works.

Why `contentView`works different?

**update**

Insert this two lines into `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
        print(" selected cell is \((cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text!)")
        print(" selected cell is \((cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text!)")
```

output:

```
selected cell is Kii Kenya0
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Project can be download here: [Link](http://github.com/williamhqs/testCollectionView/archive/master.zip)

PS: I checked the 'Installed' for the contentView's subViews.
[image] 
CollectionView in simulator.
[image]

Comment: what about `cell.subviews` or `cell?.viewWithTag()`

Comment: William, do you know how to make a subclass of a `UICollectionViewCell`? That would give you more control than accessing views by tag.

Comment: Daniel, do you know you have to subclass it just for two connections?

Comment: @HossamGhareeb It's really wired, i used ```cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2)``` on ```cellForItemAtIndexPath``` works, but only ```cell?.viewWithTag()``` works in ```didSelectItemAtIndexPath```, i guess maybe contentView is not on the view hierarchy.

Comment: Create a subclass and access your label and image through it instead of tags. That would be easier as well

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot thanks, but i prefer not create that file just for two connections.

Comment: I tried using the tags and i am able to access the elements in didSelectItemAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
import UIKit

class CollectionUIViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("customCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView).image = UIImage(named: "Image")
        (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text = "cell no \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        print(" selected cell is \((selectedCell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text!)")

    }



}
```

I get the selected cell's label text by accessing it using viewWithTag (attached snapshot for reference)
[image]

Comment: ```print(" selected cell is \((cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text!)")```
        ```print(" selected cell is \((cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel).text!)")``` the output:
 > selected cell is rowText
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: That's interesting, why it doesn't on mine, updated my questions too.

Comment: yes thats strange because it is working fine on my Xcode with cell?.viewWithTag() and also with cell.contentView.viewWithTag()

Comment: Our difference is collectionView's superView is not viewcontroler's view, it's view controller's subview, but this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: You are able to see the collection view with proper cells before tapping on any of the cell ?

Comment: yes, i checked 'installed' of the image and label, check the picture i updated.

Comment: can you also upload the collection view image after running it on simulator, i mean can you see the proper collection view cells or it shows the standard cells as in storyboard

Comment: just cross verify the tags for the label and imageView in storyboard

Comment: Sorry i am not very clear what you want to check but just upload the CollectionView part.

Comment: not able to figure out, thats weird. It works at my end and not at yours

Comment: i am using Xcode 7.0.1 and running on IOS 9 simulator, are you using the same or different version? just to verify as i am not finding any issues with the code

Comment: Same here. just created another project, same issue on my side.

Comment: Can you download it :https://github.com/williamhqs/testCollectionView/archive/master.zip

Comment: I downloaded it but the ViewController only has collection view protocols declaration and not implemented anything and there is no collection view in the storyboard as well check this https://github.com/williamhqs/testCollectionView/blob/master/testCollection/ViewController.swift

Comment: check this again, my bad. thanks for your patient help! https://github.com/williamhqs/testCollectionView/archive/master.zip